# Civil 3D and the File Geodatabase

Tags: file-geodatabase, civil3d

Is there a way to use File Geodatabases and Feature Classes, not just Shapefiles, in AutoCAD Civil 3D 2011 and any newer versions (i.e. 2013 and 2015)?

Comment: This post may help: http://www.cadtutor.net/forum/showthread.php?31633-Editing-an-ESRI-file-Geodatabase-in-AutoCAD And this one: http://forums.autodesk.com/t5/AutoCAD-Map-3D-General/Import-geodatabase-file-into-Map-3d-2015/td-p/4960762

Comment: "We have encountered a problem" can we have more details on this problem to help...

Comment: Answers consisting solely of links to other sites are [generally discouraged](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). You should try to at least summarize if not quote the information in the links, or give some general context about the information found there. These would be better posted as a comment.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.